# Always login with password into the same database, whenever query or update at any time

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, pdo

Hi stackoverflow users

I had problem with the understanding when I build the PHP website to access to the same database.
I am using PHP, PDO and MySQL. I am confused.

Do the code always have to login with password **EACH TIME** the code make query or make update to the same and only database?

If I have several databases, but sticked to the same database, does the code still have 
to login with password **EACH TIME** the code make query or make update too?

I know it is different when using MySQL console.

Please advise. Thanks

regards 
Clement

Comment: It has to be done once per script call.

Comment: You supply your credentials when you connect to the database (your new PDO call). As long as you keep a handle to that you can query all day without having to reconnect. And you can call new PDO($dsn, $username, $password) on as many databases as you need, just assign the object to a different variable for each one.

Comment: Will the handle be consistent across all php files so that I do not have to login every time I access same database for different uses? How do I ensure that this handle is consistent across all  PHP files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection remains until you either delete the PDO object or your script terminates.

If you want more persistence than that, you can set the `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` attribute when you construct your PDO object.  That allows caching of connections for queries that use the same credentials.  I'm not sure how this is affected when you connect to multiple databases in your script.

Read [Connections and Connection Management](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) on php.net.